# I get a list as a json object from a RestAPI and I want to visualize the first value of that list in node-red Dashboard

Tags: javascript, list, api, node-red

I get a list as an json object from a RestAPI and I want to visualize the first value of that list in node-red Dashboard. The "Text" node of the node-red dashboard nodes awaits of course an object and not a list. What do I have to write into the function node, which is in front of the "Text"-dashboard node?
I wrote the following code in that function node:

```
msg.payload.value.0 = msg.payload; 
msg.payload return;
```

But that is apparantly wrong. Sorry, I am totally new to this and do not have an idea how to get the first value of a list and convert into an object.

I hope you get what I mean. I just want to convert a list into an object with the function node in node.red. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have the assignment order wrong for the first line. And you need to use `[]` notation in order to access entries in an array.

Secondly you need to return the whole `msg` object from a function node (and again you have the arguments in the wrong order.

Something like this will be closer to what you need:

```
msg.payload = msg.payload.value[0];
return msg;
```

This sets `msg.payload` to the value of `msg.payload.value[0]` where `value` is an array (list) and `0` is the first element in that array.

I've had to make some assumptions about the input to the function node here, if this isn't right, then please edit the question to include a sample of the input.

Comment: thank you for your explanations (hints). I will immediately try it out when I am back home in a few hours and have access to my node.red on-premise server again :). I will report back, if your suggestion solved the problem. Then I will mark your suggestion as the answer of my question.